# setTimeout recursion with Jquery

Tags: jquery, recursion, settimeout

I'm trying to increment a value every second on the client side with jquery
this is what did:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function increment(){
            $("#counter").text(parseInt($("#counter").text())+1);
            setTimeout(increment(),1000)
        })
    </script>
```

this is not working as expected and i get a "too much recursion" error.
any ideas on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    function increment(){
        $("#counter").text(parseInt($("#counter").text())+1);
        setTimeout(increment,1000);
    };            
    increment();
});
```

By the way, there is [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to calling a function repeatedly at a set interval, rathering than recursively calling a function with `setTimeout()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    var interval = setInterval(increment,1000);     
});

function increment(){
    $("#counter").text(parseInt($("#counter").text())+1);            
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`increment()` is a *call* to increment, not a reference to it. When you're trying to set it up for increment to be called again, you're actually calling it again immediately. If it ever returned, its *return value* would be passed to `setTimeout`, but it never will because it simply calls itself again and again until you get a deep recursion error.

The solution is simply to remove the parentheses, so that you're *referencing* the function increment, and not calling it.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout(increment, 1000)` should be the right syntax since you are passing a reference to a function.

Recursively calling `setTimeout()` without a stopping criteria is not recommended. The stack will blow eventually. Using `setInterval()` should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way: "A function which is called as soon as created and repeats inside 1000 ms intervals if 'something' is not true"

```
(function(){
    if (something) {
        doSomething();
    } else {
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
    }
})();
```